# Ubuntu 18.04. How to set language (keyboard layout) change to Ctrl+Shift?

Tags: keyboard-layout, 18.04

I found Keyboards Shortcuts but it only accepts combos with 3 buttons (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+?), even for those where originally only 2 buttons are used (like original combo <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>).

So I can't change <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Can anyone explain why this is?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install *Tweaks* (package: `gnome-tweaks`). Then use Tweaks to set an **alternative** layout switcher.

Comment: Tanks a lot. it save me from buggy ubuntu 18.04.1 layout switcher.

Answer (score 7):

The full sequence of actions would be:
Ctrl+Alt+T

```
 sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
 gnome-tweaks
```

then in the window
Keyboard&Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Switching to another layout

Answer (score 0):

1- Open **Settings**>**Devices**>**Keyboard**
2- you will find the shortcut set to *super* + *space*, change it to *Ctrl*+*Shift* or whatever you want. Or you can add the shortcut that you want.

Comment: On which desktop environment does it work like that?

Comment: It **only** accepts 3 pressed keys. That is the problem.

Comment: It works on Gnome

Comment: Strangely, it accepts Ctrl+Print, but doesn't accept Ctrl+Shift.
And I can't make Printscreen of that dialog, as it accepts the combo Print or Ctrl+Print, instead of actually doing a Printscreen.

Comment: I voted for the answer proposed by @Gunnar Hjalmarsson, since it answers your question.